# Get CompoundStructureLayer Face

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

Is there any way with the Revit API to retrieve the faces of a CompoundStructureLayer?

Here is my current "extract layers" code:

```
CompoundStructure compoundStructure = wall.WallType.GetCompoundStructure();

IList<CompoundStructureLayer> layers = compoundStructure.GetLayers();

foreach (CompoundStructureLayer layer in layers)
{
    // Retrieve Faces
}
```

And this is the current get faces code:

```
GeometryElement geo = wall.get_Geometry(opt);
GeometryObjectArray objects = geo.Objects;
foreach (GeometryObject obj in objects)
{
    Solid solid = obj as Solid;
    if (solid != null)
    {
        FaceArray fa = solid.Faces;
        // Do face stuff
    }
}
```

I can't convert a CompoundStructureLayer to an Element type.. how can I extract the face info?

Comment: Are you sure CompoundStructureLayer has a faces? Wall has a faces. CompoundStructureLayer in the wall is the one of materials that wall consists. Please explain that do you want to get.

Comment: I'm trying to get the Reference object of the CompoundStructureLayer, so I can create a Dimension using the layer info. Revit already does this in the UI (New Dimensions -> Faces of Core)